# head off challenges or fend off challenges

Tags: phrase-usage

Is the phrase "head off" correctly used here? It seems to me that the author meant "fend off" because "*head off* means *to start a journey* rather than *fight against*."  I am not very sure.

> In an effort to **head off challenges** to his leadership, Chairman Mao unleashed a wave of unrest that swept across China in the 1960s.
> He wanted to root out opposition and rid the country of any semblance of old Chinese culture, social values and history.
> At the forefront of the Cultural Revolution were the Red Guards - young, radical students and fanatical supporters of Mao and his circle.  Parents and teachers were vilified and in some cases beaten and killed. Old temples, architecture and literature were destroyed too.  Saul Yeung was a member of the Red Guards. He spoke to Witness about his memories of that time and the guilt he still carries.

Source: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXAOTjNheVg)

Comment: have you looked up "head off" in a dictionary? It is a transitive verb and means "to block, to prevent" ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/head%20off#:~:text=transitive%20verb,head%20off%20the%20imminent%20crisis)).

Comment: Thank you.  Cambridge Dictionary misled me, in which it explains "head off: to start a journey or leave a place":            https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/head-off?q=+head+off+

Comment: Yes. Block or prevent, as fev says. Or "turn aside". Cowboys had to head off stampeding cattle most nights when I was young. There were no aerial shots but I think they galloped up to the front and sort of shouted at the leaders till they were diverted or were trampled by the younger bullocks. There's at least a *sense* of that in your passage about Mao.

Comment: If you ***head off*** challenges, you've ***nipped them*** [the plotted challenges] ***in the bud*** before they actually develop into ***real, manifest*** challenges that you actually have to confront (by implication, you never really had to "engage the enemy"). But if you ***fend off*** a challenge, that challenge did in fact come to pass - but you beat the challenger.